# Discord.js Issue with .includes function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot to return a message when the `arg` isn't one of the `colors` in the variable but it keeps sending this message:

[image: issue with the command]

There are two issues I couldn't fix

1. the bot sends both messages for "red"
2. the bot says "that is not a valid skin" even though I defined "black" in the colors variable

```js
let skin = db.fetch(`${message.author.id}.skin`)
        if (skin === null) skin = "red"; //red
        let skin2 = client.emojis.cache.get(e[skin])
        var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "pink", "orange", "yellow", "black", "white", "purple", "brown", "cyan", "cyan"]

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./assets/colors/${skin}.png`, `${skin}.png`);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .attachFiles(attachment) // <- add attachment
        .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}\'s skins (${message.author.id})`, message.author.avatarURL())
        .setThumbnail(`attachment://${skin}.png`)
        .addField(`Current skin`, `${skin2}`)
        .addField(`Default skins`, `red, blue, green, pink, orange, yellow, black, white, purple, brown, cyan, lime`)
        .addField(`Unlocked skins`, `none`)
        .addField(`Locked skins`, `none`)
        .setDescription(`To set a skin use ${prefix}skin <skin>`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('#00ffff')
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(embed)
        for (var i=0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            if (args[0].includes(colors[i])) {
              let skin3 = args[0]
              db.set(`${message.author.id}.skin`, args[0])
              message.channel.send(`Set your skin to ${args[0]}`)

        
            } else if(!args[0].includes(colors[i])) {
                return message.channel.send(`That is not a valid skin`)
            }
        }
```

As you can see

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "pink", "orange", "yellow", "black", "white", "purple", "brown", "cyan", "cyan"]
```

already has "black" in it but it executes the else if function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over the `colors` array and check `if (args[0].includes(colors[i]))` you check if a string includes the `colors[i]` string. [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) checks if one string (`colors[i]`) is found within another string (`args[0]`).

The example below shows how it works. It checks every item in `colors` one by one:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
const args = ['red']

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Does the string "${args[0]}" include the string "${colors[i]}"?`)
  if (args[0].includes(colors[i])) {
    console.log('yes')
  } else {
    console.log('no')
  }
}
```

#### Return statement will exit the loop

The problem is that you return `if(!args[0].includes(colors[i]))`. In a for loop a return stops execution and exits the function.

In your first example, the first item in your `colors` array is `"red"`. Inside your for loop, you check if the value of `args[0]` (`"black"`) is included in the string of `"red"`. As this is false, you return `That is not a valid skin` and exit the for loop. You don't even check the second item in your `colors` array (`"blue"`).

In your second example, your message is `"au/skin red"`. You start the for loop. The first item in your `colors` array is `"red"`. Inside your for loop, you check if the value of `args[0]` (`"red"`) is included in the string of `"red"`. As this is true, you send `Set your skin to red` but there is no `return` so this time you don't exit the loop. You check the second item in the `colors` array (`"blue"`). As this is not red, you return `That is not a valid skin` and exit the for loop. That's why you have two messages sent in your second example.

#### Array#includes

What you could use is [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). It checks if an array (`colors`) includes a certain value (`args[0]`) among its entries. You don't even need a for loop.

```js
const colors = [
  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'purple', 'brown', 'cyan', 'lime',
];
const args = ['white']

if (colors.includes(args[0])) {
  console.log(`Set your skin to ${args[0]}`);
} else {
  console.log('That is not a valid skin');
}
```

#### Working code

```js
// if fetch returns null, skin is 'red'
const skin = db.fetch(`${message.author.id}.skin`) || 'red';
const skin2 = client.emojis.cache.get(e[skin]);
const colors = [
  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'purple', 'brown', 'cyan', 'lime',
];

const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
  `./assets/colors/${skin}.png`,
  `${skin}.png`,
);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .attachFiles(attachment) // <- add attachment
  .setAuthor(
    `${message.author.tag}\'s skins (${message.author.id})`,
    message.author.avatarURL(),
  )
  .setThumbnail(`attachment://${skin}.png`)
  .addField(`Current skin`, `${skin2}`)
  .addField(`Default skins`, colors.join(', '))
  .addField(`Unlocked skins`, `none`)
  .addField(`Locked skins`, `none`)
  .setDescription(`To set a skin use ${prefix}skin <skin>`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor('#00ffff')
  .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());

if (!args[0])
  return message.channel.send(embed);

if (!colors.includes(args[0]))
  return message.channel.send(`That is not a valid skin`);

db.set(`${message.author.id}.skin`, args[0]);
message.channel.send(`Set your skin to ${args[0]}`);
```